# How to change the displayed URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'd like URLs like this:

`http://example.com/root/branch/twig/`

be rewritten and displayed to a URL like the one below:

`http://example.com/root/twig/`

At the moment, the two URLs point to the same resource so there is no difference between them on the site apart from how they look like.

I'd like wordpress to display the shorter version.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: **branch** is your category and **twig** is post name?

Comment: @ManojKumar **branch** is a custom taxonomy - in my case 'ss_category', **twig** is the name of the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shoud use some .htacess rexrite rules either than relying on the wordpress rewrite functions. It seems more appropriate in your case.

Try a rule like this :

```
RewriteRule ^root/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /root/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Insert it right after RewriteBase /

Comment: Hi Antoine, the server errors out with an "Internal Server Error" if I add this RewriteRule to Wordpress' .htaccess. I guess it's not enough just to drop it inside <IfModule>

Comment: My bad, my answer was incorrect, I updated it

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I definitely have to catch up with rewrite rules.

Comment: is it possible to include this RewriteRule in the code rather than .htaccess? I think then the site would be more portable - if, e.g. it was migrated to nginx.

Comment: You can always write worpdress rewrite rules but you should be aware that it might not give you the same results since it will try to find a page/post type first.

.htaccess rewrite rules can be ported to nginx, see this tools for example [here](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) or [here](http://www.anilcetin.com).